# How to return the data of another model instance model by using joins in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, inner-join, laravel-models

I want to return the data of `Charge` instance instead of `User` , for that i am trying to use joins ,can you please help me to acheive this thing

```
  $id=Charge::whereNotNull('created_by')->get('created_by')->toArray();
        foreach($id as $name){
            $id[] = $name['created_by'];
        }
        return $v=User::whereIn('id',$id)->where('username',$request->data)->get();
        }
```

for this i am trying to use left join , relationship available between created_by and id (I am trying to convert above queries into single query)

```
$v=Charge::whereNotNull('created_by')->leftJoin('User',function($join){
            $join->on('Charge.created_by','=','User.id');
        })->get();
```

Comment: Do you have a relationship in your models? ```public function user(){ return $this-hasMany(Charge::class, 'id', 'created_by'); } ``` ?

Comment: `return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'created_by');`  like this available in charge model

Comment: and you have the inverse on user? then you can just do ``` return User::with('charge')->get(); ``` or ```return Charge::with('user')->get();``` or if not all charges have users ```return Charge::whereHas('user')->get();```